# How can i change bot nickname in Discord.js without message/messageCreate event in every one minute?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to change the bot nickname every minute. I tried   `message.guild.members.cache.get(bot.user.id).setNickname("Botnickname" +"✅")         message.guild.me.setNickname("Botnme" +"✅")` and it only works when someone writes/sends a message(using messageCreate) event.

But I just want to change the nickname every minute without using any events. Like changing the username of a bot `bot.user.setUsername("BotUsername")`. I can directly change the bot username instead of the nickname but there is a limit to changing the username so what can be a possible solution for changing only nicknames without any events?

Answer (score 2):

nickname property can only be changed in a guild, so it require an event, but you can make an interval in the ready like this

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  const guild = 'id';
  setInterval(() => {
    client.guilds.cache.get(guild).me.setNickname('nick')
  }, 60000);
});
```

Comment: `client.guilds.cache.get(guild).me.setNickname('nick')`  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'me')

Comment: @SumanRajKhanal either the ID is wrong, or you did not put it in the ready event

Answer (score 0):

You can set it as a cron job, which requires no event. Just the bot to be online.

```js
const cron = require('node-cron')
const guildId = 'putGuildIdNumberHere' // edit this line

cron.schedule('*/1 * * * *', function() { //triggers every minute on the minute
    const nicknames = [
        "Name 1",
        "Name 2",
        "Name 3",
        "" // in case you want it to show its real name every once in a while
    ]
    client.guilds.cache.get(guildId).me.setNickname(nicknames[Math.floor(Math.random() * nicknames.length)]) 
// picks a name randomly from the list
})
```